# Unable to print array into HTML

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have a program which is pulling data from the database like so.

**Views.py**

```
def final(request):
total = []
name = []
k = 0
for i in Question.objects.raw("SELECT name, question1, question2, question3, question4, question5, question6, question7, question8, question9, question10 FROM music_question"):
    name.append(str(i.name))
    total.append(int(i.question1) + int(i.question2) + int(i.question3) + int(i.question4) + int(i.question5)
                 + int(i.question6) + int(i.question7) + int(i.question8) + int(i.question9) + int(i.question10))
return render(request, 'music/final.html', {"totals": total, "names": name, "rows": Question.objects.all()})
```

From here I'm trying to print into HTML like so

**final.HTML**

```
    </body>
<script type=text/javascript>
data = {{totals}}
console.log(data)
</script>
</html>
```

I can see that the data from the database has returned to the console in Chrome but it won't persist onto the web page and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. [image: Console output Chrome]

Comment: I can't see any output to html markup in your code. Do you have it ? 
You put your totals into javascript tag, not to html markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should put `data = {{totals}}` before `</body>` tag, or I did not understand you ?

Comment: I think this was the problem it is now printing all the data out of the database.